# Ionic Firebase Authentication on device

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4, device

I wish to use Firebase Authentication. I am using [FirebaseUI-Angular](https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/firebaseui-angular) and everything works good in a browser. However the social media logins don't work on device. When I click login with google, the device browser shows up and... nothing happens.

So my question is: Is there any WORKING approach how to get Firebase Authentication work on device using Ionic?

Comment: Here is a guide from Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova However, it does not work in my case, because cordova-universal-links-plugin is deprecated and there is an bug, so I am to able to build my project then. Here is guide from Ionic itself: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication but it seems it does not work for browser and it seems to be more difficult to setup, because you need idToken and accessToken for Google auth.

Comment: any working solutions in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with [FirebaseUI-Angular](https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/firebaseui-angular).  It appears to be built to support web-based apps. Ionic requires Cordova plugins for Facebook and Google login capability. These plugins can work with Firebase Authentication.

I have a [ionic-firebase-auth-starter](https://github.com/RichTillis/ionic-firebase-auth-starter) repo that uses Firebase for authentication. It does not have Facebook or Google sign in built in but it does provide a working approach to get Firebase Authentication working on a device using Ionic.

If you decide to clone my project... Follow the Step 1 and Step 2 of the web setup [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) from Firebase. Then copy the config object for your web app with [these](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) instructions and paste it into src\environments\environment.ts (replacing the existing Firebase config object).

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   firebaseConfig: {
   apiKey: "AXXXXXBILN60aW-XXXXXXXXIZWeHkMDUVT-AQ7Y",
   authDomain: "fir-auth-test-XXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://fir-auth-test-XXXXX.firebaseio.com",
   projectId: "fir-auth-test-XXXXX",
   storageBucket: "fir-auth-test-XXXXX.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "106XXXXXXX396",
   appId: "1:106XXXX87396:web:d384fXXXXXXXXd647bed31",
   measurementId: "G-XNXXXXXXB0"
  }
```

Once you have Firebase email auth setup, you can follow [this](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-facebook-login) tutorial to setup a Facebook app and register it with your Ionic app using the Cordova plugin.

Once you have the Facebook plugin setup correctly you can use it to login to Firebase. Your code would look something like the code example below (Note: this is not the entire  AuthenticationService class, its only the Facebook specific code):

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from "@angular/fire/database";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from "@ionic-native/facebook/ngx";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private facebook: Facebook) {}

  loginWithFacebook(): void {
    this.facebook
      .login(["public_profile", "email"])
      .then(
        (res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
          const facebookCredential_1 = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
            res.authResponse.accessToken
          );
          this.loginWithFirebase(facebookCredential_1).then(
            console.log('success');
          );
        },
        error => {
          console.log( JSON.stringify(error));
        }
      )
      .catch(error_1 => {
        console.log("Error ", error_1);
      });
   }

   async loginWithFirebase(credential: firebase.auth.AuthCredential) {
     return firebase.auth()
       .signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
       .then(response => {
          return response;
     })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Hope it helps